# Need to apply wait after function call so that next function gets called after 1st function has executed

Tags: excel, vba, asynchronous

I want to run 2 functions in one button click. I assigned a macro to button and inside this macro call, i have two functions - Func1 and Func2. Now Func1 internally works on async pattern. And execution control moves to Func2. Since Func1 has not completed internally, I donot want excel vba to jump to Func2. Ideally Func2 should work only when Func1 has completed job of writing on cell depending on some logic.

Can someone suggest me how to proceed on this? Should I apply wait? I do not know how much time Func1 will take, also wait will make excel not responding. Can someone please guide me.

Comment: Not much detail to go on, but you could monitor the range being written to by Function 1 for changes.

Comment: Please include your relevant code part or a [mcve]. There is no good general solution to this, so more details (your code) is needed.

Comment: @TimWilliams - I end up with your solution and it worked. So I called third function Func3 after Func1 and in Func3 i ran loop till particular cell value did not change, and then finally my Func2 call invoked. So all in all Function execution was in line and in sync. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

If you want to have two functions run with one button click you can call the second function at the end if the second function (No wait needed) ex:

```
Private Function Func1()

'Code Here for Func1 

Func2 'This calls the second function

End Function
```